# How to slice Excel data using win32com in Python (3.6)

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have data in Excel that I want to split.

Here is my code

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\bin256.xlsx')
ws = wb.ActiveSheet
input_number = ws.Range('U4:U15363')
number = [input_number[i:i+60] for i in range(0,len(input_number),60)]
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    number = [input_number[i:i+60] for i in range(0,len(input_number),60)]
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    number = [input_number[i:i+60] for i in range(0,len(input_number),60)]
  File "C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 256, in __getitem__
    return self._get_good_object_(self._oleobj_.Invoke(dispid, LCID, invkind, 1, index))
TypeError: Objects of type 'slice' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT
```

How can I fix that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just want to open excel?
Maybe you can try pandas

```
import pandas as pd
file_path=r'E:\download\tmp\test.xlsx'
file_path='./tmp/test.xlsx'
df_name.to_excel(file_path,sheet_name='Sheet1',index=False)
```

Comment: i want to split data every 60